# How to check if a section of C++ code is being compiled?

Tags: c++

I'm working in a pretty large codebase, and I don't really understand how the build system works. I added a C++ function into the code, but I get an undefined reference error at runtime, which tells me the part I added may not be getting compiled.

I am wondering how I can check if a particular part of a file is being compiled or not?

Comment: If you can share an example that triggers the same error and at least the text of the error we might be in a better place to help with your issue.

Answer (score 7):

Insert anything that would cause an error.  For example:

```
#error
```

Comment: Minor caveat - historically some compilers e.g. MSVC would allow syntax errors inside uninstantiated function templates ,  so specifically using preprocessor is a better idea than trying random erroneous-looking code

Comment: @M.M Might that be ancient history now though?

Comment: @PaulSanders not everyone builds using the latest version -- there are plenty of legacy production codebases around that can only be compiled with a certain old version of compiler

Comment: @M.M True [filler]

Answer (score -1):

compile in debug mode run the code and add a breakpoint in the area you suspect and if its not compiled it will not let you to break there

Comment: Good idea, but the OP's problem is the other way round.